# Retrieving @Test description form testNG tests

Tags: java, automation, testng

I have the following format on my testNG tests:

```
@Test(alwaysRun = true, dependsOnMethods = "testStep_1", description = "Enter the names, and verify that they are appearing correctly ")
public void testStep_2() throws Exception{
}
```

Is there a way to implement something that could read all test descriptions, and by that generating a test documentation.
I tried to somehow include `ITestNGMethod getDescription()`  to a `afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult)` so after each method is run, the description is returned, but with no success.
Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is by using ITestResult.

```
    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod arg, ITestResult arg1) { 
      System.out.println(arg.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
      System.out.println(arg1.getMethod().getDescription());
    }
```

The second sysout will return a (String) description of the invoked test method.

Answer (score 5):

We tried something similar. Below is the method that print the testng test name and test description for each method.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(Method method) {
    Test test = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
    System.out.println("Test name is " + test.testName());
    System.out.println("Test description is " + test.description());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it is:

```
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
System.out.prinln(result.getMethod().getDescription());
}
```

This should give you the description parameter of the @Test annotation

Answer (score 2):

IMethodInterceptor implementation allows you to access all your tests annotations and their parameters.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.IMethodInstance;
import org.testng.IMethodInterceptor;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Interceptor implements IMethodInterceptor
{

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context)
    {
        int methCount = methods.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < methCount; i++)
        {
            IMethodInstance instns = methods.get(i);
            System.out.println(instns.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(Test.class)
                    .description());
        }

        return methods;
    }

}
```

Add implemented class to your listeners list. So that TestNG know about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this, without defining a listener interceptor, as I show in [this GitHub project I made](https://github.com/djangofan/extent-reports-testng-example).

Basically, define a TestBase class like this:

```
public abstract class NGTestBase extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    ....
    private String testDescription;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(Method ngMethod)
    {
        ...
        setTestDescription(ngMethod);
        ...
    }

    ....

    public String getTestDescription()
    {
        return this.testDescription;
    }

    private void setTestDescription(Method methodInstance)
    {
        this.testDescription = methodInstance.getAnnotation(Test.class).description();
    }

}
```

Then, in your test, just annotate them like this:

```
@Test(description = "Test printing out all the Spring beans.")
public void printAllBeansTest(Method ngMethod)
{
    ...
    String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    ...
    for (String beanName : beanNames)
    {
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "BEAN[" + beanName + "] : " + applicationContext.getBean(beanName).getClass().toString());
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public class ReportSet_MethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
        if (iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().isTest()){
            System.out.println("TestCaseName:" + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getDescription());
        }
    }`

Comment: Just some code is not an answer to the question. Please add some explanation.