# TestNG Custom Reporter include test description instead of name

Tags: xml, testng, test-reporting, test-results

I want to implement a custom reporter for TestNG xml test results.
I currently use JUnitReportReporter.
My result xml currently looks like this:

```
testcase name="testSearchForProductAndVerifyFirstFoundItem" time="55.516" classname="com.jpard.jaf.test.SearchForAnItemTests"
```

I simply want to replace testcase name with the Test Description
as in @Test(description = "Test that first item in the results is the one searched for").
How can I do that in the simplest way possible.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it simple **extending JUnitReportReporter class and overriding getTestName** method to show in xml report **method name and description**. The class looks like this:

```
public class CustomReporter extends JUnitReportReporter {

@Override
protected String getTestName(ITestResult tr) {
    return tr.getMethod()
             .getMethodName() + ": " + tr.getMethod()
                                         .getDescription();
}
```

}

I hope it helps anyone looking for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to implement [`IMethodInterceptor`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.12-g09766d5-166/javadoc/org/testng/IMethodInterceptor.html) interface which will return a list of method instances , [`IMethodInstance`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.12-g09766d5-166/javadoc/org/testng/IMethodInstance.html)  and then
from that list get all instances one by one and then

```
desc = instance.getMethod().getDescription();
```

method [getDescription()](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.12-g09766d5-166/javadoc/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html#getDescription--)

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871486/retrieving-test-description-form-testng-tests)